# Acción al dejar pulsada UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy programando mi aplicación y estoy buscando la forma de llevar a cabo una acción cuando dejo pulsada una celda de la tabla. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo en Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añado la versión en Swift 2.x para tenerlo como referencia.

Este sería el método para añadir el *long press*

```
let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

Y este otro el método que lo maneja

```
func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let p = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.myTableView)

    guard let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(p) else {
        print("long press on table view but not on a row")
        return
    }

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .Began:
        print("long press on table view at row \(indexPath.row)")
    default:
        print("gestureRecognizer.state = \(gestureRecognizer.state)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer esto deberías agregar un *long press gesture recognizer* al `UITableView`.

Por ejemplo, [esta respuesta en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924965/135050) explica cómo hacerlo.

---

***Traducción***:

Primero agrega el *long press gesture recognizer*:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

Luego, en el método que maneja el *long press*:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %ld", indexPath.row);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.state = %ld", gestureRecognizer.state);
    }
}
```

Debes tener cuidado con que esto no interfiera con el *tap* normal de la celda, y también notar que `-handleLongPress:` se puede disparar varias veces antes de que el usuario levante el dedo.

Comment: Hola buenas! Gracias por el aporte pero es Obj-C y yo estoy programando en Swift... ¿Alguna otra solución?

Comment: @JaviRando No debería ser difícil traducirlo a Swift, el código es el mismo pero cambia la sintaxis... ¿Qué dificultad tuviste al pasarlo a Swift?